# Python script can be run manually in my Raspberry Pi 4, but it cannot be executed automatically every 5 PM through crontab

Tags: python, cron, raspberry-pi

I would like to run a python script called `process.py`

It did the job when i type through the terminal such as python3.9 /home/pi/Program/process.py

Then I set it up into crontab with the idea so it can run automatically every 5 PM with format like this --> 0 17 * * 1-5 python3.9 /home/pi/Program/process.py , but it doesn't work as i type it manually in the terminal

Please help, i have been going through this issue for hours and cannot find the solution

Comment: "but it doesn't work". Right. No code, error message, information about the error. How do you expect a random stranger on the internet to be able to help you without any informaion about what the problem actually is?

Comment: PS: this may also be a permissions issue (cron runs processes under a different user than your main user), so start checking that

Comment: hi @GPhilo when i run manually it never gives any error message. and when it comes to 5PM, there is nothing pop up on my screen as well, so i can't address where is the issue in this case.. sorry that i can't provide enough information

Answer (score 1):

If `python3.9` is not in /bin it'll crash.
Also, cron runs with `sh`, for specifying `bash` you should run `bash python3.9 /home/pi/Program/process.py`

1. Try providing it a full path, like `/usr/local/bin/python3.9 /home/pi/Program/process.py`
2. Run `sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep -C 5 cron` to see what was the exact error and continue from there.

- syslog can also be under `/val/log/messages`

Comment: hi @EvgenyKoyakov thanks for your information. I will try to put the full path and let's see if this will solve the issue tonight.. 

But what i don't understand is why this partially work on specific program and not work on the other. So the process.py is the only beginning of the whole steps and it doesn't do the job through crontab, but 10 minutes later, the nextprocess.py can run and send me the automatic email report

Comment: No clue mate, that need a deeper investigation.